Can we construct this index of meta-contained elements in ZFC?
I'm trying to better understand models of ZFC with infinite descending chains of containment (as in Model of ZF with Infinite Descending Chain), and wanted to check that certain constructions are valid in ZFC.
Define $x \in^n y$ (meta-containment) if there is a function $f$ with domain $\{0,\ldots,n\}$ with

$f(0) = x$
$f(i) \in f(i+1)$
$f(n) = y$

I.e. a sequence $x \in \cdots \in y$ of length $n+1$.
Given a set $T$, can we use replacement to construct a function $f$ with domain $\omega$ such that $f(n) = \{y | y \in^n T\}$?
Can we use some form of choice to construct the set of all sequences (finite or infinite) $\mathbf{x}$ with $x_0 = T$ and $x_i \ni x_{i+1}$? What about the set of all maximal such sequences?

You can ... as long as you keep separate the distinction between "internal" and "external" notions.
Suppose $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. Then there is some element $\omega^M$ which $M$ thinks is the first infinite ordinal. The definition you give can be implemented internally in $M$, by recursion along $\omega^M$. However, this will not generally agree with the external notion. E.g. if $M$ is an $\omega$-nonstandard model and $\alpha$ is a nonstandard finite Zermelo ordinal in $M$, then $0\not\in^n\alpha$ for any standard $n$ but $M\models\exists n\in\omega^M(0\in^n\alpha)$ via an $n$ which is in $\omega^M\setminus\omega$.
